# django count rows by column

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a model like this

```
class tbl_invoice(models.Model):
    invoice_id                      = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    client_id                       = models.ForeignKey(tbl_customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invoice_number                  = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    date                            = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    total_amount                    = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    total_tax                       = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    discount                        = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    paid_amount                     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    balance                         = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

a client can obviously have multiple invoices and I want to show all the invoices according to clients in a table

like

```
Customer           Total Invoices            Total Amount        Total Tax

Client1                  10                      50000              200
Client2                   8                      10000              500
```

I tried this

```
tbl_invoice.objects.values('client_id').order_by().annotate(Count('client_id'))
```

but this gives

```
<QuerySet [{'client_id': 19, 'client_id__count': 5}, {'client_id': 21, 'client_id__count': 10}, {'client_id': 24, 'client_id__count': 15}]>
```

this does give the count of rows but how can I get other data??

sorry if this is a duplicate, but I just can't figure out this simple query.

Comment: You must to put the name of the field that you want in the `.values`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must count the invoice id. Try this:

```
tbl_invoice.objects.values('client_id').order_by().annotate(Count('invoice_id'), Sum('total_amount'), Sum('total_tax'))
```

instead of this

```
tbl_invoice.objects.values('client_id').order_by().annotate(Count('client_id'))
```

Comment: yeah it gives total invoices per client, but how can I get total_amount or total_tax??  do I have to use another subquery on this queryset??

Comment: Maybe try using a list? 

`annotate(Count(['client_id', 'total_amount', 'total_tax']))`

Tell me if it works, so that i will add it to answer

Comment: no, it didn't worked and gave this error `Complex annotations require an alias`  i tried this ```tbl_invoice.objects.values('client_id').order_by().annotate(Count(['client_id', 'total_amount', 'total_tax']))```

Comment: it gave this ```<QuerySet [{'client_id': 19, 'invoice_id__count': 2, 'total_amount__count': 2, 'total_tax__count': 2},{'client_id': 24, 'invoice_id__count': 1, 'total_amount__count': 1, 'total_tax__count': 1}]>```   i need total no. of invoices per client and their total amout sum... if that helps... sorry if I am not being very clear as I am myself stressed out on this part

Comment: Updated tax and amount columns to Sum. If it doesn;t work, try with sum in lowercase

Comment: finally!!! it worked as expected!! thanks a lot, brother...